# Number of numbers up to n with k set bits

Tags: binary

Is there a way to (efficiently) compute the number of numbers up to $n$ with $k$ set bits?

Some values for low $n$ and $k$ as an example (perhaps $n$ is off by one); "#" is the number of set bits in the binary representation of $n$ ("Hamming weight", `popcnt`).

```
 n    #     k=0  k=1  k=2  k=3  k=4
------------------------------------
0000  0      1    0    0    0    0
0001  1      1    1    0    0    0
0010  1      1    2    0    0    0
0011  2      1    2    1    0    0
0100  1      1    3    1    0    0
0101  2      1    3    2    0    0
0110  2      1    3    3    0    0
0111  3      1    3    3    1    0
1000  1      1    4    3    1    0
1001  2      1    4    4    1    0
1010  2      1    4    5    1    0
1011  3      1    4    5    2    0
1100  2      1    4    6    2    0
1101  3      1    4    6    3    0
1110  3      1    4    6    4    0
1111  4      1    4    6    4    1
```

While trying to figure out a solution I eventually realised, that this is relatively straight forward when $n$ is a power of 2 (because all *combinations* of bits are guaranteed to appear). In that case the value I am after is $f_k(n)=C{log_2(n)\choose k}$. But as far as I can see this does not help for arbitrary $n$.

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do it is the same as the number of ways to select k from n. N choose K.

Comment: @mathreadler  No, because not all choices are allowed.  If $n=1001$, say, and $k=1$, and $k=2$, then $1100$ is not valid.  Of course the simple binomial method works if $n=2^m-1$.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I misunderstood.

Comment: I misunderstood it as all n bit binary numbers but the n was the max cap of the number, not number of bits.

Comment: Yes the function nCk will be valid for powers of 2 only.